# Firefox for Android refuses to display a list item, a plain vanilla HTML page. Why?

Tags: android, css, firefox

So maybe I'm just overlooking something super basic but this is stumping me. I have an extremely simple test case: a plain HTML page, simple as can be, with two paragraphs and an unordered list, which has an ID, and one list item in the list. Here's what's baffling me:

- If the `<ul>`'s `id` attribute is `social-media`, then *the list item inside the list will not be rendered by Firefox for Android*.
- If the `<ul>` does not have an `id` attribute *or* has an `id` attribute whose value is *literally anything other than `social-media`*, then the list item inside the list *will* be rendered.

Is `social-media` a reserved ID value? For completeness, here's the entire test case, where the list item will not show up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Missing List Item Test Case</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>This paragraph is visible.</p>
        <ul id="social-media">
            <li>This list item is not visible if and only if the parent UL has an ID of "social-media". Why?</li>
        </ul>
        <p>This paragraph is also visible.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also for completeness, my Android device is running KitKat (4.4.x) and my Firefox is version 35. There are no software updates available for either.

**In what circumstances can the value of an ID attribute *alone*, without any CSS files or other styling information, cause a rendering disparity on only one browser?** Is this a bug in Firefox?

*Edited to add:* Looks like Firefox also refuses to display the list item if the `<ul>` element's `id` value is `socialmedia` (no dash), but will display the list item if the `id` value is something like `blahblahblah` or `societysucks` and basically anything else.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know AdBlock did that. And you were totally right. I didn't even remember I had AdBlock installed. Thank you! I was about to think I was literally going insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by Ad-blocking software. Often an option on these is to prune out social-media type tasks and one of the ways it identifies these is through element attributes. You can also find if you use font-awesome or something along those lines it disables certain icons.

Comment: *facepalm* That was it. This is why I should never code at 3:30 AM after an otherwise equally frustrating day. I am off my game, yo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by running the code through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

```
<htma lang="en">
```

Should be

```
<html lang="en">
```

(htm**l** not htm**a**)

Comment: LOL! Thank you. :) That was definitely an error on my part (I should've copy-and-pasted). However, I have fixed that silly mistake and the issue persists. :(